# Not able to install window from dipy.viz after installing fury

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am working on a project with dipy. However, when I try to visualize an image using dipy.viz, I get the error `cannot import name 'window'`. However, I have already run `!pip install fury` (this is in Google Colab by the way). Here is my code:

```
!pip install fury
from dipy.viz import window, actor, has_fury

if has_fury:
    ren = window.Renderer()
    ren.add(actor.peak_slicer(csa_peaks.peak_dirs,
                              csa_peaks.peak_values,
                              colors=None))

    window.record(ren, out_path='csa_direction_field.png', size=(900, 900))

    if interactive:
        window.show(ren, size=(800, 800))
```

Let me know what I need to do to fix this error.

~Samuel

Comment: In [here](https://pypi.org/project/fury/) it says fury requires `Numpy (>=1.7.1)`,  `Vtk (>=8.1.0)` and `Scipy (>=0.9)`. Install these before run your code. And also you have to install `vtk` in manual mood. you can get whl file in [here](https://pypi.org/project/fury/#files).

Comment: @Kalana all those dependencies already have those versions installed. What else must I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://pypi.org/project/fury/), fury requires `Numpy (>=1.7.1)`, `Vtk (>=8.1.0)` and `Scipy (>=0.9)`. Install these before run your code. If you get errors when installing `vtk` you have to install it in manual mood. you can get whl file in [here](https://pypi.org/project/fury/#files).

If you have already installed that libraries and still getting that error, then try to **restart** your pc. Then run your code. Because some libraries need restart after the installations.

**Note -:** If you are using python 3.x version, it is good to use `pip3` command when installing libraries.